# El juego de la Vida de Conway: ¿El array this.arrayCells termina teniendo los mismos valores que this.arrayCellsModificado?

Tags: javascript, html5, clase, canvas, motor-de-juego

Estoy recreando el Juego de La Vida de Conway en HTML5 y Javascript usando Canvas sin ningun framework o libreria.

La ultima vez, la vida habia brotado muy bruscamente, y al parecer, eso era debido a que mientras se iteraba el array bidimensional que contenia las celulas muertas y vivas, mientras se iteraba uno po uno, se modificaba ya el valor en el array del juego y esto no tenia que ser asi, sino que se tenia que modificar esto en un array temporal, y luego del bucle for, asignarlo como valor al array original

Pues eso hice con this.arrayCells (el array original) y this.arrayCellsModificado (el array temporal)

En vez de inicializar el array aleatoriamente, lo modifique logrando que inicie con el patron del planeador. Solo para ver si este funcionaria, y como lo esperaba, no "planea"

El codigo se basa mas en la Clase JuegoDeLaVidaDeConway, donde hay una funcion en su constructor que actualiza el array original, reseteandolo, añadiendo los elementos (lo mismo que se ve en el bucle for de abajo que lo inicializa con todo 0, antes eso lo inicializaba aleatoriamente) y luego asignarle el valor de this.arrayModificado,

Como las celulas que he puesto que estan vivas, estan todas en el centro del mapa y ninguno no esta en sus bordes, solo lo que "importa" digo yo, vendria ser el ultimo else if del bucle for del metodo o funcion update() que evalua aquellas celulas que no esten en ningun borde o esquina.

Yo espero a que la vida funcione como lo dice sus reglas, pero creo que el array original termina, ademas de tener los datos viejos, los datos nuevos, y se.supone que la anterior generacion ya no es la misma que hoy, ni combinada con la de hoy

¿Que es lo que pudo haber pasado en el codigo que me de este comportamiento?

Aqui el codigo completo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Juego de la Vida de Conway </title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
        <canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script>
class JuegoDeLaVidaDeConway {
    constructor(c, colores, WCells, HCells) {
        this.c = c;
        this.colorVivo = colores.vivo;
        this.colorMuerto = colores.muerto;
        this.ctx = this.c.getContext("2d");
        this.WCanvas = this.c.width;
        this.HCanvas = this.c.height;
        this.WCells = WCells;
        this.HCells = HCells;
        this.WCellSize = this.WCanvas / this.WCells;
        this.HCellSize = this.HCanvas / this.HCells;
        this.arrayCells = [];
        this.arrayCellsModificado = [];
        
        this.actualizaArray = function() {
            this.arrayCells = [];
            
            for(let y = 0; y < this.HCells; y++) {
                this.arrayCells.push([]);
                for(let x = 0; x < this.WCells; x++) {
                    this.arrayCells[y].push(0);
                    }
                }
            
            this.arrayCells = this.arrayCellsModificado;
            }
        
        for(let y = 0; y < this.HCells; y++) {
            this.arrayCells.push([]);
            this.arrayCellsModificado.push([]);
            for(let x = 0; x < this.WCells; x++) {
                //this.arrayCells[y].push(Math.floor(Math.random()*1.1125));
                this.arrayCells[y].push(0);
                this.arrayCellsModificado[y].push(0);
                }
            }
        this.arrayCells[19][20] = 1;
        this.arrayCells[20][21] = 1;
        this.arrayCells[20][22] = 1;
        this.arrayCells[19][22] = 1;
        this.arrayCells[18][22] = 1;
        }
    draw() {
        for(let y = 0; y < this.arrayCells.length; y++) {
            for(let x = 0; x < this.arrayCells[y].length; x++) {
                this.ctx.fillStyle = (this.arrayCells[y][x] == 0) ? this.colorMuerto : this.colorVivo;
                this.ctx.fillRect(x * this.WCellSize, y * this.HCellSize, this.WCellSize, this.HCellSize);
                }
            }
        }
    update() {
        for(let y = 0; y < this.arrayCells.length; y++) {
            for(let x = 0; x < this.arrayCells[y].length; x++) {
                if(y == 0 && x == 0) { //izquierda arriba
                    let Vecinos = this.arrayCells[y][x+1] + this.arrayCells[y+1][x+1] + this.arrayCells[y+1][x];
                    if(this.arrayCells[y][x] === 1) {
                        if(Vecinos == 2 || Vecinos == 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 1;
                            }
                        else if(Vecinos < 2 || Vecinos > 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    if(this.arrayCells[y][x] === 0) {
                        if(Vecinos == 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 1;
                            }
                        else {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                else if(y == 0 && x != 0 && x != this.WCells - 1) { //arriba central
                    let Vecinos = this.arrayCells[y][x-1] + this.arrayCells[y+1][x-1] + this.arrayCells[y+1][x] + this.arrayCells[y+1][x+1] + this.arrayCells[y][x+1];
                    if(this.arrayCells[y][x] === 1) {
                        if(Vecinos == 2 || Vecinos == 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 1;
                            }
                        else if(Vecinos < 2 || Vecinos > 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    else if(this.arrayCells[y][x] === 0) {
                        if(Vecinos == 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 1;
                            }
                        else {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                else if(y == 0 && x == this.WCells - 1) { //derecha arriba
                    let Vecinos = this.arrayCells[y][x-1] + this.arrayCells[y+1][x-1] + this.arrayCells[y+1][x];
                    if(this.arrayCells[y][x] === 1) {
                        if(Vecinos == 2 || Vecinos == 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 1;
                            }
                        else if(Vecinos < 2 || Vecinos > 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    else if(this.arrayCells[y][x] === 0) {
                        if(Vecinos == 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 1;
                            }
                        else {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                else if(x == this.WCells - 1 && y != 0 && y != this.HCells - 1) { //derecha central
                    let Vecinos = this.arrayCells[y-1][x] + this.arrayCells[y-1][x-1] + this.arrayCells[y][x-1] + this.arrayCells[y+1][x-1] + this.arrayCells[y+1][x];
                    if(this.arrayCells[y][x] === 1) {
                        if(Vecinos == 2 || Vecinos == 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 1;
                            }
                        else if(Vecinos < 2 || Vecinos > 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    else if(this.arrayCells[y][x] === 0) {
                        if(Vecinos == 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 1;
                            }
                        else {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                else if(y == this.HCells - 1 && x == this.WCells - 1) { //derecha abajo
                    let Vecinos = this.arrayCells[y][x-1] + this.arrayCells[y-1][x-1] + this.arrayCells[y-1][x];
                    if(this.arrayCells[y][x] === 1) {
                        if(Vecinos == 2 || Vecinos == 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 1;
                            }
                        else if(Vecinos < 2 || Vecinos > 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    else if(this.arrayCells[y][x] === 0) {
                        if(Vecinos == 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 1;
                            }
                        else {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                else if(y == this.HCells - 1 && x != 0 && x != this.WCells - 1) { //abajo central
                    let Vecinos = this.arrayCells[y][x-1] + this.arrayCells[y-1][x-1] + this.arrayCells[y-1][x] + this.arrayCells[y-1][x+1] + this.arrayCells[y][x+1];
                    if(this.arrayCells[y][x] === 1) {
                        if(Vecinos == 2 || Vecinos == 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 1;
                            }
                        else if(Vecinos < 2 || Vecinos > 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    else if(this.arrayCells[y][x] === 0) {
                        if(Vecinos == 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 1;
                            }
                        else {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                else if(y == this.HCells - 1 && x == 0) { //izquierda abajo
                    let Vecinos = this.arrayCells[y][x+1] + this.arrayCells[y-1][x+1] + this.arrayCells[y-1][x];
                    if(this.arrayCells[y][x] === 1) {
                        if(Vecinos == 2 || Vecinos == 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 1;
                            }
                        else if(Vecinos < 2 || Vecinos > 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    else if(this.arrayCells[y][x] === 0) {
                        if(Vecinos == 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 1;
                            }
                        else {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                else if(x == 0 && y != 0 && y != this.HCells - 1) { //izquierda central
                    let Vecinos = this.arrayCells[y-1][x] + this.arrayCells[y-1][x+1] + this.arrayCells[y][x+1] + this.arrayCells[y+1][x+1] + this.arrayCells[y+1][x];
                    if(this.arrayCells[y][x] === 1) {
                        if(Vecinos == 2 || Vecinos == 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 1;
                            }
                        else if(Vecinos < 2 || Vecinos > 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    else if(this.arrayCells[y][x] === 0) {
                        if(Vecinos == 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 1;
                            }
                        else {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                else if(x != 0 && x != this.WCells - 1 && y != 0 && y != this.HCells - 1) {
                    let Vecinos = this.arrayCells[y-1][x-1] + this.arrayCells[y-1][x] + this.arrayCells[y-1][x+1] + this.arrayCells[y][x+1] + this.arrayCells[y+1][x+1] + this.arrayCells[y+1][x] + this.arrayCells[y+1][x-1] + this.arrayCells[y][x-1];
                    if(this.arrayCells[y][x] === 1) {
                        if(Vecinos > 1 && Vecinos < 4) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 1;
                            }
                        else if(Vecinos < 2) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 0;
                            }
                        else if(Vecinos > 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    else if(this.arrayCells[y][x] === 0) {
                        if(Vecinos == 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 1;
                            console.log(x, y);
                            }
                        else if(Vecinos != 3) {
                            this.arrayCellsModificado[y][x] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        this.actualizaArray();
        }
    }

window.onload = function() {
    window.c = document.getElementById("c");
    window.ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    
    window.W = innerWidth;
    window.H = window.W;
    
    c.width = W;
    c.height = H;
    
    window.Game = new JuegoDeLaVidaDeConway(c, {vivo: "white", muerto: "black"}, 50, 50);
    animate();
    }
    
function animate() {
    c.width = W;
    Game.draw();
    Game.update();
    
    setTimeout(animate, 120);
    }
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Una sugerencia, lo que tienes dentro de cada bloque if-else de primer nivel (los que están justo despues de los for) es prácticamente igual exceptuando el cálculo de vecinos. Deberías extraer esa parte a una función, de forma que tu código se redujera y fuera más legible y fuera más fácil encontrar posibles errores.

Comment: Y para encontrar ayuda, son demasiadas líneas para que nadie las revise minuciosamente.